# Linkedlist Using Solid Principles-C#

Tags: c#, linked-list, text-files, singly-linked-list

I have my code for linked list  here I have attached below, In this all methods are declared in a single class, now I am refactoring my code so I am moving my methods to separate class, after moving my data to separate class my data is not getting passed which so my data is not getting displayed, I think my way of passing the data through the variables to other classes is where the problem occurs, I don't know how to rectify this..here I have attached my code..

here is my code:

```
//My node class:
public  class Node
{
  public int info;
  public Node link;
  public Node(int i)
  {
    info = i;
    link = null;
  }
} 
// My class to print the data:
public class Display
{
 public void DispalyList()//list to display the items
 {
  Node p;
  SingleLinkedList lst = new SingleLinkedList();
  if (lst.start == null) // I have a doubt whether calling the start variable using that object is not correct., If data is being passed here I can proceed further
  {
   Console.WriteLine("List is empty");
   return;
  }
  Console.Write("list is: ");
  p = lst.start; //The way of calling the start object is wrong I guess
  while (p != null) // p value is null here
  {
   Console.Write(p.info + " ");
   p = p.link;
  }
   Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
// My Single Linked list class://for time being i have two methods in this class
public class SingleLinkedList
{
 public Node start;
 public SingleLinkedList()//constructor
 {
  start = null;
 }
 public void CreateList() //Method  where I am inserting the data
 {
  int i, n, data;//variable declaration
  Console.Write("enter the number of nodes");
  n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  if (n == 0)
  return;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
   Console.WriteLine("enter the element to be inserted");
   data = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   InsertAtEnd(data);
  }
}
public void InsertAtEnd(int data)//Method to insert the data into the list
{
 Node p;
 Node temp = new Node(data);
 if (start == null)
 {
  start = temp;
  return;
 }
  p = start;
  while (p.link != null)
  p = p.link;
  p.link = temp;
}
}
}  
//Main class using switch case:// I am just calling the display method alone for time being
public class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)//Main program calling the methods
 {
  int choice;
  SingleLinkedList list = new SingleLinkedList();
  list.CreateList();// calling the createlist method
  while (true)
  {
   Console.WriteLine("1.Display List");
   Console.WriteLine("Enter your choice");
   choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   if (choice == 13) //I have 13 cases for time being I have shown only one below
   break;
   switch(choice)//Switch case calling the methods
   {
    case 1:
    Display dis = new Display();
    dis.DispalyList();//calling display method which prints the data 
    break;
    default://default case
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Choice");
   }
 }
```

}
}

Here is my above code, in which the value of the start in the[ DisplayList()] method is assigning null.If the data is being passed to it in this method i can follow the same for my other classes too. I don't know how to assign the data here..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `ReadAllLines()` instead, which will return a collection of strings, one per line in your input:

```
public class ReadingTextFile: IReadingTextFile {
  public IEnumerable<string> content() {                  // change the return type
   string path = @ "C:\Users\s\Desktop\Datas\Data Input.txt";
   var data = File.ReadAllLines(path);                    // and this
   return data;
  }
 }
```

Then you can either just use the `file.content()` if all you need is a list:

```
 IReadingTextFile file = new ReadingTextFile();
 LinkedList < string > data = new LinkedList < string > ();
 IEnumerable<string> inp = file.content();  // this is a collection of strings, one per line of your input
 // ...
```

Or if you still want a linked list, you can just use the LinkedList constructor that takes a collection:

```
 public class Readingtolist {
  public void Input() {
   IReadingTextFile file = new ReadingTextFile();
   Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

   sw.Start();
   IEnumerable<string> inp = file.content();    // the reading the file is probably what you really want to time.
   sw.Stop();

   var data = new LinkedList<string>(inp);    // note the use of (inp) here
   Console.Write("\n time Taken For Read Data: {0} ms",
    sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
   Console.WriteLine("\n The items are{0}", inp);
  }
 }
```

Comment: @ njenson thanks it worked .. but if i wanted to use  node also which means then how i have to do with this

Comment: each time while reading it is showing different different time..why is it so i dont understand

Comment: @ShaktiS it will vary depending on what other programs or operations your machine is running at the time you run your test. Your program has to compete with others on your computer for the same resources.